# What is the meaning of "Warning message: In adf.test(dfrn) : p-value greater than printed p-value"?

Tags: r, time-series

[image]

I am working on temperature data of 4 years.After differencing, I applied ADF test.  what is the meaning of that warning??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation in `help("adf.test")` says this:

> The p-values are interpolated from Table 4.2, p. 103 of Banerjee et
>   al. (1993). If the computed statistic is outside the table of critical
>   values, then a warning message is generated.

The highest value in that table is p = 0.99. You get the warning, because for your data the p-value is larger. Usually, the information p > 0.99 should be sufficient for all practical purposes.

Comment: Thanks for the information Roland. What method should I follow to get p value less than 0.99?

Comment: Collect data that is less conforming to the H0? I don't understand the question.